# changing the z-index of an element based on whether other elements overlap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have seen you can change the priority of an entire element with z-index, but I was wondering if you can change the z-index for a portion of an element only while a higher element is "on top" of it (the higher element has higher z-index).

Simply put, can the same block (a square shaped div element) have multiple different z-indexes and slide below/above other elements, or is z-index for an element monolithic? Something like

```
footer{
   z-index: 5
}

div .slide-under-footer {
  z-index: 10;
}

div .slide-under-footer:overlapping footer{
  z-index 0
}
```

I want my item to slide under the footer gracefully (the footer is fixed to the bottom) because the footer is transparent and I want to see the background at the bottom in the transparent footer, and as scroll down the middle body is all that scrolls. Amazingly, now that I look for it, I can't find a single example site

I would prefer to use bootstrap.

[image]

Please note

[image]

versus

[image]

Comment: Basically you want conditional CSS? No, I don't think so I confess I don't quite understand what you a re trying to do.

Comment: I really just want the background to be in that U shape and take up the entire left, right, and bottom of the page...then I want the body to be scrollable (the body may be fed unlimited objects and be single page, or be scrollable for a long distance). I really don't care how I do it. I didn't see a bootstrap example though on their site

Comment: When you scroll down, I only want the middle body box to change. I have a fixed footer and header working with simple bootstrap, but now the body overtakes the footer and hogs the bottom middle of the page (it covers up the part of the picture with text "Footer with background visible")

Comment: It's not a really footer then it's a page background...isn't it?

Comment: yes. I do have 4 buttons down there, they're the "main" nav buttons. but yes it's a background, I just want those 4 buttons visible (above the background. Right now the buttons are above the background and the background can be seen but ONLY if the body has few articles

Comment: You can't have different parts of elements having different z-indexes. But you can do what you want to do, just make sure you layer it correctly. Bottom of the pile will be the background with z-index: 0 (presumably fixed), body next with z-index: 1, footer fixed with z-index: 2. Because footer is a higher z-index, the body will scroll right under it...

Comment: What's happening Luke is my body has higher z-index than background and covers it. Please see pics above to see if it's still feasible

Comment: the background is one logical picture and let's me know what section of the app I'm at. If I just wanna read articles I have a bookshelf there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I am not certain I understand your problem, I think you can look up CSS's **stacking context**, maybe it can solve your problem.

> Not all z-indexes are created equal, however: an element’s z-index only determines its ordering relative to other elements in the same stacking context. Most elements on a page are in a single, root stacking context, but absolutely or relatively positioned elements with non-auto z-index values form their own stacking contexts (that is, all of their children will be z-ordered within the parent and not be interleaved with content from outside the parent).

An example:

*If element A (fixed) has z-index 1, and another unfixed element B has z-index 2, yet another element C (child of A) has z-index 3. If you render them in Chrome, B is above C, because C is in A's context, and B is above A, B-C-A.*

Posts:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Stacking-Changes-Coming-to-position-fixed-elements